# How to increase the time offset of a module?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, articles, module-display

I'm using the GK News Show Pro 5 module for displaying my articles. I have a problem with the publishing of the articles, because it appears 24 hours after I publish the article. I changed the time offset of the module to +12, then to 0, and then to -12, but the result is the same. What could be the matter?

Comment: What's your timezone set to in the Joomla Global Configuration?

Comment: Universal time.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you are viewing cached content on your browser.
Is this happening only for this module, are you able to see other updated content?

### About Cache

- First of all, set the module time offset to 0.
- Then go to **System->Clear Cache** and empty all the cached files.
- Do also a **Purge Expired Cache** just in case.
- Clear your **Browser's cache** and refresh your page.
- See if the module has updated its content.

#### Cache Settings in Joomla:

1. **Global Configuration**->**System tab**
2. Individual Modules Cache setting: For GK Module you can find it in the **Basic Settings** tab.
3. **Plugin Manager->System - Page Cache plugin**

#### Other reasons for getting cached content:

- Some hosting providers, offer site speed-enhancements services, which they cache the website's output.
- CDN services also serve cache content
- htaccess settings may also instruct the browser to cache content.

Comment: This is only happening with that particular module. I will experiment with the cache settings a little though.

Answer (score 0):

1. You check your server time?
2. You check your server time zone in System >> Global configuration >> Server >> Location Settings :: Server Time Zone* ?
   You need config to same time in both.